# get partial string contained in "()" from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df:

```
      MinMaleTA

28    888(G2M)
29    888(AAM)
30    888(G2M)
31    888(G2M)
32    888(AAM)
33    888(G2M)
34    888(G2M)
35    888(AAM)
36    888(G2M)
37    888(G2M)
38    888(G2M)
39    888(G2M)
40    888(AAM)
41    888(G2M)
42    888(G2M)
43    888(G2M)
```

sometimes more than 3 digit string inside '()',like:

```
 28 888(G2MPTM)
```

How can I the string between '()' in MinMaleTA.

something like:

```
result = df['MinMaleTA'].startwith"(" and endwith")"
```

the output for the first 2 rows  should be:

```
G2M AAM
```

Comment: simply `.str[-4:-1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract` method with a regex:

```
>>> df['MinMaleTA'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')
      0
28  G2M
29  AAM
30  G2M
31  G2M
32  AAM
33  G2M
34  G2M
35  AAM
36  G2M
37  G2M
38  G2M
39  G2M
40  AAM
41  G2M
42  G2M
43  G2M
```

`\(` and `\)` match the character `(` and `)`

`(.*)` is the capturing group that match any number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You got example how to use `regex` but if string has always the same construction and the same size inside `( )` then you can slice

```
"888(G2M)"[-4:-1]

result = df['MinMaleTA'].str[-4:-1]
```

and if it has the same size outside then you can use `4` instead of `-4`

```
"888(G2M)"[4:-1]
"888(G2MPTM)"[4:-1]

result = df['MinMaleTA'].str[4:-1]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also split on `(` and skip last char

```
"888(G2M)".split("(")[-1][:-1]
"888(G2MPTM)".split("(")[-1][:-1]

df['MinMaleTA'].str.split('(').str[1].str[:-1]
```

or you can also split on `)` but this create longer code

```
"888(G2M)".split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]
"888(G2MPTM)".split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]

df['MinMaleTA'].str.split('(').str[1].str[:-1]
```

If you have more complex text then you can also use `.apply()` to run some longer code.

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MinMaleTA': ['888(G2MPTM)', '888(GTM)']
})

result = df['MinMaleTA'].str[4:-1]
print(result)

result = df['MinMaleTA'].str.split('(').str[1].str[:-1]
print(result)

result = df['MinMaleTA'].str.split('(').str[1].str.split(')').str[0]
print(result)

def convert(text):
    #return text[4:-1]
    #return text.split("(")[1][:-1]
    return text.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]

result = df['MinMaleTA'].apply(convert)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not always sometimes more than 3 digit string inside '()',like 28    888(G2MPTM)

Comment: if you have always 3 digits before `(` then you can use `4` instead of `-4`. If you have different sizes before `(` and inside `( )` then you can also use `split("(")` and `split(")")`.